# I have an error in dataflow: Error processing pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an error in dataflow: Error processing pipeline

when i run this code with DirectRunner works but when i run this code with DataFlowRunner i have this error:

this the error:

```
ERROR:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:Console URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/jobs/<RegionId>/2023-04-05_02_00_47-7238238223888513941?project=<ProjectId>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 51, in <module>
run()
File "test.py", line 44, in run
output | 'Write' >> WriteToText("gs://<bucket>/output/wc.txt")
File "/opt/py38/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 601, in __exit__
self.result.wait_until_finish()
File "/opt/py38/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1555, in wait_until_finish raise DataflowRuntimeException( apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error: 
Error processing pipeline.
```

in iam i have this rule:

- Storage Object Administrator
- BigqueryConnectionCustom Role
- SQL Cloud Clients
- BigQuery data editor
- Dataflow developer
- Service account user
- BigQuery user
- Compute Viewer
- Worker Dataflow

the code is:

```
import os

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


def pipelineOptions(pipeline_args):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args,
        runner="DirectRunner",
        project=<project-name>,
        job_name="testbigquery",
        temp_location=<temp-location>,
        region=<region>
        )
    return pipeline_options


def run(argv=None):
    print("Start Process")
    pipeline_options = pipelineOptions(argv)
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    with pipeline as p:
        lines = p
        counts = (
                lines
                | 'Split' >> (beam.Create(["test", "fix", "test"]))
                | 'PairWithOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
                | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
        def format_result(word, count):
            return '%s: %d' % (word, count)
        output = counts | 'Format' >> beam.MapTuple(format_result)
        output | 'Write' >> WriteToText("gs://<bucket>/output/wc.txt")

    print("End Process")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Seems you're hardcoding the runner and it crashes on the cloud because you need to specify dataflow runner.

Comment: i have that error when i set runner="DataFlowRunner". But when i set runner="DirectRunner" the job works.  I want it to work when i set dataflow

Comment: Have you check worker logs, job logs and diagnostics tab ?

Comment: yes i have only this log and nothing else: 2023-04-14 09:31:13.671 CEST Error processing pipeline textPayload: "Error processing pipeline.".

Comment: i resolved! i add this parameter --service_account_email with the correct service account.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @luca, who is also the OP, the error has been resolved by adding `--service_account_email` in the parameter with the correct **service account** when using **DataFlowRunner**.

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this has been answered in the comments but not posted as an answer. This will be for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.